# How to open an SGF file with an external application in an android app?

Tags: python, android, kivy

I'm trying to open an SGF file (a format popular for storing go games) in an external app. My current code manages to fire up an app which then fails to load it by default. I can't seem to change this behaviour.

Using other apps to open the file I get inconsistent behaviour. The file browser says there is no app capable of opening sgf files and redirects me to the play store (regardless of which of the apps I subsequently install). However, the internet browser gives me a popup telling me to choose one of 2 suitable apps. I would like to have the same behaviour in my app, where the user can explicitly select the app to open it with.

My current code (which does seem to open an app, show a message 'failed to load' and quits, not hitting the exception):

```
file = self.files[self.file_ix]
if platform == "android":
    from jnius import autoclass

    Intent = autoclass("android.content.Intent")
    Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')
    PythonActivity = autoclass("org.renpy.android.PythonActivity")
    try:
        intent = Intent()
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file), "application/x-go-sgf")
        PythonActivity.mActivity.startActivity(intent)
    except Exception as e:
        self.hint.text = f"No SGF Viewer found: {e}"
else:
    os.system(f"xdg-open '{file}'")
```

How can I change it to get the popup with the choice of apps?

Comment: Which apps did you install that can handle such files?

Comment: @blackapps I have Ah Q Go (which tries to open the file and fails, although it handles web downloads fine) and BWGo-Free (an SGF reader which generally works)

Comment: `intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file)`. What is the full path of the file? Now adays you cannot use a file uri any more. It should cause a FileUriExposedException even before the user can choose an app. You should use a FileProvider instead.

Comment: it's a local path, e.g. "problems/1a. tsumego beginner/CHO CHIKUN Encyclopedia Life And Death - Elementary/prob0018.sgf"

Comment: Changing it to an absolute path does give the exception about files exposed. Looking into this file provider it seems it needs XML files which don't seem available in a kivy app.

Comment: I googled for `kivy fileprovider` and there is lots of info. Further i do not program in Kivy and cannot solve your problem.

Comment: Simply because there are lots of google result doesn't mean there is a lot of info. The most relevant search result is a yet to be merged PR. But thanks for your help so far.